# Configuring same button for multiple events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a form button in my web app, (purely made with Vanilla Js), The form is used to get data from user and when button is clicked, that data goes to a HTML table and so on.

To edit Table Row, I have placed Edit Button on the table column (at every row), image attached below would help to get clear idea:

[image: App Screenshot]

The Blue Submit Button is Named as "addButton" , when the user clicks "Edit" of particular row in table, corresponding data is Shown In Input Field, So user can fill in new details.

Up to here is everything fine, now the real problem begins: After user edits the info in Input fields, Blue Submit button is used for saving those changes and spontaneously show change in table as well. (this is the required behaviour).

Instead what is happening is : The modified row is shown in table as well as a new entry is made in row with same details ("addButton" event listener is executed twice, once for saving changes done by user, and once for adding new item in row).

I have placed this event listener (same name, because I do not want separate buttons for saving edited info) twice.
For clarity, please look at code:

(this is first addButton event listener in global scope - used for adding new entry to table)

```
addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var obj = {
        id : object.count,
        date : formatDate(inDate.value, inMonth.value),
        day : inDay.value,
        item : inItem.value,
        price : parseInt(inPrice.value),
    };
    object.info.push(obj);
    object.count += 1;
    refreshDOM();
});
```

For "Edit and Delete" buttons in row, I have this:
`modifyBtn` is tied to table, so I can get click target with that.

(Inside `modifyBtn` second addButton event listener is present - used for saving changes and show output in table)

```
modifyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.classList[0] === 'editInfo'){
        var eid = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        var eindex = getIndex(eid);
        
        inDay.value = object.info[eindex]['day'];
        inDate.value = parseInt(object.info[eindex]['date'].substr(0,2));
        inMonth.value = object.info[eindex]["date"].substr(4);
        
        inItem.value = object.info[eindex]['item'];
        inPrice.value = object.info[eindex]['price'];
        addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            object.info[eindex]['day'] = inDay.value;
            object.info[eindex]['date'] = formatDate(inDate.value, inMonth.value);
            object.info[eindex]['item'] = inItem.value;
            object.info[eindex]['price'] = parseInt(inPrice.value);
            refreshDOM();
        });
    }
    if(e.target.classList[0] === 'deleteInfo'){
        var did = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        var dindex = getIndex(did);
        console.log(dindex);
        object.info.splice(dindex,1);
        refreshDOM();
    }
});
```

**So after editing when user clicks blue submit button, I want only that `addButton` event listener to execute which is inside `modifyBtn` event listener,
Currently both `addButton` event listeners are getting executed. *Sorry for Huge explanation.***

Comment: Hey Krupesh! I've got a working fix, but it's quite long so please bear with me as I write it up :-)

Comment: Sure, why not. waiting eagerly for the solution. By d way did u try using the app, input some data into table then editing it. Did you notice the bug i described in question above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue, as you're likely aware, is that you're assigning multiple click listeners to the same element (a behaviour that you want) at the same time (a behaviour you don't want). There are a couple of ways you could fix this.

---

## The fastest fix

The quickest way to solve your problem would be to use [`.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). With this, you can remove the previous click listener (the one that adds a new element to the `info` array) before you create the second click listener that sets the edited data.

At the end of the second click listener function, you would rebind the first click listener again so the behaviour returned to normal.

#### Pros of this solution

1. It's the fastest way to solve the problem you're having

#### Cons of this solution

1. Unbinding and rebinding event listeners can make it hard to reason about your code
2. In order to remove an event listener, you need to supply the original function (like `.removeEventListener("click", listenerFunction)`. As you are currently using an [anonymous function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), you'll have to move the functions currently inside click listeners elsewhere and name them (so that you can pass them to the `removeEventListener` function
3. It's not actually clear *which* event listener is bound to `addButton` at any one time

### The solution

We need to move the function declaration for `addButton` *outside* of `.addEventListener` and give it a name. I've called it `addItemClickHandler` but you can call it whatever you want:

```
function addItemClickHandler(e) {
    var obj = {
        id : object.count,
        date : formatDate(inDate.value, inMonth.value),
        day : inDay.value,
        item : inItem.value,
        price : parseInt(inPrice.value),
    };
    object.info.push(obj);
    object.count += 1;
    refreshDOM();
}

addButton.addEventListener("click", addItemClickHandler);
```

This should work exactly the same. Now we need to move the second event listener function you're trying to add into its own named function. As we're only referring to the name of the function from inside itself, we don't even need to move it out, just give it a name. I'm going to give it `editItemClickHandler`:

```
addButton.removeEventListener("click", addItemClickHandler);
addButton.addEventListener("click", function editItemClickHandler(e){
    object.info[eindex]['day'] = inDay.value;
    object.info[eindex]['date'] = formatDate(inDate.value, inMonth.value);
    object.info[eindex]['item'] = inItem.value;
    object.info[eindex]['price'] = parseInt(inPrice.value);
    refreshDOM();

    addButton.removeEventListener("click", editItemClickHandler);
    addButton.addEventListener("click", addItemClickHandler);
});
```

- As you can see, we first remove the listener `addItemClickHandler` so that when you click on the "Add" button, it won't do anything
- We then bind a *different* click listener, that we give the name `editItemClickHandler` so we can remove it after the edit is complete
- We do all the edits we need to do
- Finally, we *remove* the new edit click listener we created and re-add the original click listener, so the functionality goes back to normal

---

## The more robust fix

[Here is a codepen of your application after applying the following fixes.](https://codepen.io/samholmes33/full/djMBvX/)

The above solution is the fastest way to fix your problem, but there are more robust ways to ensure a working solution. In this solution, I'm going to tidy up some of your code in order to make it cleaner and easier to understand.

#### Pros of this solution

1. We won't have to unbind or rebind any click listeners
2. It's easier to reason about what's happening

#### Cons of this solution

1. It'll take longer to implement, as it requires restructuring more of your code

### The solution

#### Step 1: Keep track of whether we're editing or not

Firstly, as we're not rebinding click listeners, we need to keep track of what we're editing. Let's create an object called `editing` just below `object`:

```
var editing = {
    mode: false,
    index: null
};
```

This will let us keep track of whether or not we're editing anything (`editing.mode`), and what the index of the item we're editing is (`editing.index`).

#### Step 2: Update the `addButton` event listener to use the `editing` object

Next, we need to modify our `addButton.addEventListener` to use this new `editing` object:

```
addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (editing.mode) {
        var info = object.info[editing.index];

        info['day'] = inDay.value;
        info['date'] = formatDate(inDate.value, inMonth.value);
        info['item'] = inItem.value;
        info['price'] = parseInt(inPrice.value);

        editing.mode = false;
    } else {
        var obj = {
            id : object.count,
            date : formatDate(inDate.value, inMonth.value),
            day : inDay.value,
            item : inItem.value,
            price : parseInt(inPrice.value),
        };
        object.info.push(obj);
        object.count += 1;
    }

    refreshDOM();
});
```

- If `editing.mode` is `true`, when the `addButton` is clicked, it will update the values and then disable `editing.mode`, putting it back to the way it was before
- If `editing.mode` is `false`, it will simply add the item to the array (same code as you had before)
- No matter what happens, the DOM will get refreshed

#### Step 3: Update the `modifyBtn` event listener to use the `editing` object

Also, I've noticed you're using classes to modify programmatic behaviour instead of `data-` attributes. This is fine in a lot of cases, but for your exact use case of determining the behaviour, it's recommended to use `data-` attributes instead. We should also set the `href`'s to `#`, as we don't need to use them as links:

```
<td><a href="#" data-id={{id}} data-action="edit">Edit</a> | <a href="#" data-id={{id}} data-action="delete">Delete</a></td>
```

Now, I've restructured your `modifyBtn.addEventListener()` to handle a these aspects differently:

```
modifyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = e.target;
    var id = parseInt(el.dataset.id);
    var index = object.info.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
    var info = object.info[index];
    var action = el.dataset.action;

    if (action === "edit") {
        editing.mode = true;
        editing.index = index;

        inDay.value = info['day'];
        inDate.value = parseInt(info['date'].substr(0,2));
        inMonth.value = info["date"].substr(4);
        inItem.value = info['item'];
        inPrice.value = info['price'];
    }

    if (action === "delete") {
        object.info.splice(index, 1);
    }

    refreshDOM();
});
```

- Using [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) means that the browser wont navigate to the `#` href when clicking on the link
- I've moved duplicate code where it retrieved `eid` and `eindex` no matter what action you were performing ('editing' or 'adding') outside of those functions
- As we are now editing something, we set the `editing` object to have `enabled: true` and whatever the index of the current item we're editing is
- Instead of using `object.info[eindex]` every time, I've assigned it to a variable
- You no longer need to keep your `getIndex` function, as you can use [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead
- The recommended way to get `data-` attributes is to use [`element.dataset.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead of `element.getAttribute()`
- As is standard now, no matter what happens the DOM will get refreshed

#### Step 4: Add a dynamic form header

Alright, awesome! So this totally works. One final thing I'd like to do is make it more clear what is happening, so in your `index.html` under your `<div class="form-modal">`, I'm going to add an ID to your `h2`:

```
<h2 id="form-header">Add Item</h2>
```

Then, back at the top of `index.js`:

```
formHeader = getElement('form-header');
```

And then finally in `refreshDOM()`:

```
formHeader.textContent = editing.mode ? "Edit Item" : "Add Item";
```

This will update the text inside `<h2 id="form-header"></h2>` to depending on whether or not it's being edited. This is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), and is often used as a quick way to choose different outcomes depending on a boolean variable.

---

I hope this wasn't too much information. I've spent a while looking at your code and really wanted to help with best practices and such! Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Reading your Answer, will let you know after iimplementing it. By the way found similar Stack overflow thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115000/javascript-stop-additional-event-listeners

Comment: Checked and Understood your whole answer. It proved very helpful, i felt like my creating account in stackoverflow was like a blessing. So good answers people like you give. 

I appreciate your way of explaining, everything brought down in simple steps.
It must have taken your valuable time to understand my app and remove bugs. Thanks a lot.

I am a college student, would like to build things with people. I am beginner in this field of working, frankly never worked with anyone before. Would you consider me as a part time to work with you and create something great!

Comment: Tiny Help, Could you just rewrite this line in plain old javascript here in comments: index = object.info.findIndex(item => item.id === id);

Comment: So glad I could help, you're most welcome! And that is plain old javascript :) If you'd rather not use it though, your best bet is probably just to put back your `getIndex()` function instead, as that's all it does!

Comment: I just fully read your message, and keep at it! I'm also a college student so I'm afraid I'm not a position to hire you  practice makes perfect! The more you build the better you get.

Comment: I wrote it with bit poor grammar i guess, i was just asking to build something- a web app, or a cool forum kind website, a very tiny startup kinda thing, together. I am good at front End UI/UX designing and have made several projects.
My portfolio kind website :
https://krupesh.netlify.com

Just let me know if you are interested in Building something Impactful. I am also a Newbie and have never worked in a paid project yet. :-)